# Wtforms - How FieldList receives input from frontend

Tags: frontend, wtforms, fieldlist

I am curious how `FieldList` of wtforms works, I did some experiment with the front end using javascript.

So basically I have a multiple repeatable fields, and there is a button to dynamically add new field and changes its `id`, `name`, `for` following the wtforms convention (e.g. `transaction-item-0-something` for first field, `transaction-item-1-something` for second field, etc).

One experiment that I did was putting same `id` and `name` same for 2 of field list (e.g. `transaction-item-0-something` for 1st field, `transaction-item-0-something` for 2nd field). and wtforms only took the first input value (is expected).

Second experiment was the one that bugs me, I deliberately changed some of the number so it would skip some number (`transaction-item-0-something` for 1st field, `transaction-item-2-something` for 2nd field), and it worked fine, wtforms received both of the input.

So this makes me wondering, do `id` and `name` not need to be ordered? if so how the wtforms handle the received input then, is just getting the all the ids of item which contains `transaction-item-x-something`? and just loop through it but also check if the registered id is in there?

Comment: Hello, how do you find out what the id is for each entry of the fieldlist? I'm confused how to call each entry in a template?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just dug through the [source code](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/fields/core.py#L894) and found out the order does not matter, as long as it is a number (`.isdigit()`), it will loop through all the received data and then put it inside a `set` which is like python `keys` in `dictionary`, so duplicate value will be removed.

Which means html will send every `<input>` regardless of its `id` or `name` is same and let the backend handles it